# Filling in gaps in a PostgreSQL Time Series

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, window-functions

My problem starts with a set of tables that take the following general form:

```
CREATE TABLE data_table (
  entity_fk     integer,
  timestamp     timestamptz,
  value         bigint
);
```

For each **entity_fk**, a **value** datapoint is inserted every 30 seconds to 2 minutes, so the time between insertions is not constant.

The normal selection pattern is to get all data points for a single **entity_fk** for a particular day.  This data is then graphed/visualized.

For the visualization software to be able to properly display/annotate gaps in the data, I need to have the SELECT fill in gaps in the time series with **value**s of NaN for this **entity_fk**.

So here's what I want to do:

For this data, breaking down the 24 hour period into 4 minute windows, then filling in only those 4 minute windows that don't contain ***any*** timestamps for a particular entity_fk with evenly distributed 30 second timestamps with NaN values.

My conceptual approach to this so far has been:

1. Start with CTEs to break this down into manageable parts.
2. SELECT all rows for a particular **entity_fk** for a particular DATE derived from the **timestamp**.
3. SELECT (using generate_series) a series of timestamptz spaced 30 seconds apart for the entire 24 hour period comprising the chosen DATE, each with a **value** of NaN and an **entity_fk** the same as the one we're looking for
4. Use a window function (n-tile?) to split up the entire 24 hour period of the particular DATE into 4 minute windows.
5. For any 4 minute window that has no real data, substitute the generated rows.  Any 4 minute window that **does** have real data of any kind will remain as is.

I'm able to perform steps 1-3 individually, but not in a CTE context.  I'm at a complete loss as to how to perform steps 4-5.

Here's an example (over a very short time range) of what I get when I SELECT all of the available timestamps for entity_fk 7:

```
 entity_fk |       timestamp        | value
-----------+------------------------+-------
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:00:00+00 |     1
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:00:32+00 |     2
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:01:14+00 |     3
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:01:54+00 |     4
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:02:49+00 |     5
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:03:39+00 |     6
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:13:00+00 |     7
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:13:48+00 |     8
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:15:04+00 |     9
```

And here's what I'd like it to look like, filling in the gap between values 6 and 7:

```
 entity_fk |       timestamp        | value
-----------+------------------------+-------
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:00:00+00 |     1
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:00:32+00 |     2
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:01:14+00 |     3
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:01:54+00 |     4
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:02:49+00 |     5
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:03:39+00 |     6
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:04:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:04:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:05:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:05:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:06:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:06:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:07:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:07:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:08:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:08:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:09:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:09:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:10:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:10:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:11:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:11:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:12:00+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:12:30+00 |   NaN
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:13:00+00 |     7
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:13:48+00 |     8
         7 | 2016-04-05 13:15:04+00 |     9
```